# Importing node modules with electron and Systemjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, systemjs

I just wondered if it is possible to make systemjs use require("remote").require("nodemodule"), if system js can't find the module in its own registry?

I think something like this mechanism is already working when using electron with typescript and commonjs modules...

Has someone already solved that struggle?

Comment: Looks related to the same problem I solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41351751/322984).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after some time I found a working solution:

```
var node_modules = ["child_process","fs"];
var fetch = System.fetch;
window.remote=require("remote");
System.fetch = function () {
    var promise= fetch.apply(System,arguments);
    return promise.then(function (js) {
        for(var m of node_modules){
            var requireExpression = 'require("'+m+'");';
            var remoteRequire = 'remote.require("'+m+'");'
            js=js.replace(requireExpression,remoteRequire);
        }
        return js;
    });
}
System.import("aurelia-bootstrapper");
```

Just add all imported node_modules to the array and things are fine